# AWS codeBuild: Multiple input source into one output artifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have angular client and Nodejs server deployed into one elasticBeanstalk.
The structure is that I put angular client files in 'html' folder and the proxy is defined in .ebextensions folder.

```
-html
-other serverapp folder
-other serverapp folder
-.ebextensions
....
-package.json
-server.js
```

Everytime when I do a release, I build angular app and put it into html folder in the node app, zip it and upload to elasticBeanstalk.

Now I want to move on to CICD. Basically I want to automate the above step, use two source(angular and node app), do the angular build and put it into html folder of node app and generate only one output artifact.

I've got to the stage where have separate pipeline works for each app. I'm not very familiar with AWS yet, I just have vague idea that I might need to use aws lambda.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The output artifact your CodeBuild job creates can be thought of as a directory location that you ask CodeBuild to zip as artifact. You can use regular UNIX commands to manipulate this directory before the packaging of the artifacts. Following 'buildspec.yml' is an example:

```
version: 0.2


phases:
  build:
    commands:
      # build commands
      #- command
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mkdir /tmp/html
      - cp -R ./ /tmp/html

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: /tmp/html
```

Buildspec reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax